# Citing inline "AuthorYear" and "Title - Journal Name" in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, biber

This question is most similar to [Citing Author inline and Year in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82161/citing-author-inline-and-year-in-footnote-using-biblatex). However, the respondents placed considerable effort in customizing the behavior of Year. I want to preserve the default behavior of biblatex and customize *only* the position of where the fields are presented.

This is what I want:

> As described by Feynman 1975<sup>1</sup> we find that lorem ipsem dolor. Similarly Schrodinger 1954<sup>2</sup> found doe re mi fa so la.

In the footnotes we have:

> <sup>1</sup> Symmetries of the Super Kind; 1975. *Physical Review Letters* 
>   <sup>2</sup> Searching for my Cat; 1954. *Journal of Missing Animals*

Thus the meta question is, how to customize what fields are printed inline vs. in footnote without modifying *ibid* behaviors?

---

**EDIT**

---

Given @Jon comment below - lets narrow the scope to modifying only the following fields:

1. First_Author_LastName
2. Year
3. Published_In
4. Title

\autocite should give: 
**Inline:** First_Author_Lastname YEAR<sup>#</sup>  
**Footnote:**<sup>#</sup> Title YEAR Published_In

Comment: Depending on your knowledge of `biblatex`, you might want to qualify 'simply'. What you are asking for can amount to designing a whole new style. For example, will *only* articles be cited? Is there also a reference section (and, if so, how different is it from the citations)? Will authors always appear in the text and therefore must never (be able to) appear in the footnotes? The list is actually quite long, so you should think very carefully about the complete specification before you start hacking.

Comment: @jon you're right. I did not consider how to make the solution gracefully deal with books, interviews, lectures, etc. The document that motivated this question is using authortitle-icomp style. \autocite gives you  "<superscript #>" Inline and and the footnote gives you *all* authors and full title. I'm citing mostly medical journals where there are lots of very low impact journals. Thus distinguishing a citation from JAMA vs. The Journal of Naturopathic and Holistic Cures is important. Do you suggest I narrow the scope to type articles only or expand the specification to books, lectures, etc?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, from your question it looks like the document uses an `authoryear`-like style, but your comment above mentions `authortitle-icomp`, or are you referring to the linked question there? Would it be possible to cook up a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can be sure to start with the correct assumptions. If you want to extend this scheme to other entry types, what would you print (`books` don't have a journal, is the publisher interesting?). Do you want this on all citations of a work or only the first?

Comment: @moewe AuthorTitle-icomp gives you: **inline** <sup>#</sup> and **footnote** <sup>#</sup> _Author Names;_ _Title._  I picked it as starting point only because it gives me the title in the footnote. An MWE is not a problem to make, but of zero utility since it only serves to illustrate the default behavior of biblatex & AuthorTitle-icomp. As you point out, perhaps AuthorYear is a better starting point.

Comment: @moewe I really didn't think through how to deal with non articles. You point is well taken, the publisher is meaningless for books.

Comment: An MWE would help me since I would then assume that you are OK with the basic style of the references and only want certain changes applied. The bibliography for `authortitle` is different to that from `authoryear`. You focus exclusively on the citations in your question, so am I to assume you would be OK with any format in the bibliography? `biblatex` styles are a delicate and complex matter, changes can affect many areas in an existing document.

Comment: I usually stick to `IEEE` style which relies on numerical citations. However, since this time I wanted to have more visibility on what articles I am using, so I switched to `authortitle` for citations while trying that keep  `IEEE` for bibliography. It didn't work; but, strict bibliography formating isn't essential for this doc (not going to be submitted to a journal) so I let it stay on `authortitle.` In considering your questions I'm looking through the citations, and yeah, there are a bunch of problems with  `webpage`, `book`, `thesis` - all except `article` class.

Comment: I don't think there is much point in doing this if you use numerical citations, then the reader will have to go to the bibliography in the back anyway, pestering her with footnotes in a way gives away the advantage of normally quite unintrusive behaviour of numerical citations. Using numerical citations with author-title citations doesn't seem to be sensible to me either. Please see my answer below for a solution based on `authoryear-ibid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a small modification of the cite macro (we assume `authoyear-ibid` here)

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{cite:extrainfo:article}}}
    {}}
```

You can replace `\ifentrytype{article}` with `\ifboolexpr{not test {\ifciteibid} and test {\ifentrytype{article}}}` or even `\ifboolexpr{not test {\ifciteseen} and test {\ifentrytype{article}}}` (for the last suggestion you need to enable the `citetracker`).

Where the new macro `cite:extrainfo:article` is

```
\newbibmacro{cite:extrainfo:article}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \newunit
  \printlabeldateextra
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
}
```

MWE with `\ifboolexpr{not test {\ifciteseen} and test {\ifentrytype{article}}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, backend=biber, citetracker=true, giveninits=true, uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro{cite:extrainfo:article}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \newunit
  \printlabeldateextra
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\ifciteseen} and test {\ifentrytype{article}}}
    {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{cite:extrainfo:article}}}
    {}}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{geer} and \cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{worman} and \cite{baez/article}  and \cite{baez/article}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output of text and footnotes]

*edit* Code modernised for `biblatex` v3.8 and newer. See the edit history for an older version.